# Why my site's header has an extra large bottom margin in IE?

Tags: css

This is how it looks like on Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

But in IE looks like this:

[image]

What could be causing this?

Relevant CSS:

```
#header #inner-header {
position: relative;
width: 90%;
max-width: 940px;
min-width: 770px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header #mainbox {
width: 90%;
max-width: 940px;
margin: 22px auto 0 auto;
min-width: 490px;
z-index: -1;
}

iframe {
margin-top: 120px;
}
```

Live site:

http://carleighmac.org/

Comment: In which IE version ?

Comment: In the future, consider using a CSS reset as part of your page.  It's a great way to avoid browser inconsistencies with CSS.  Here's a popular one I use:  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: `header` tag is part of HTML5. this will not work in older browsers like IE.

Comment: @swapnesh That screenshot is IE10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `nav#navigation`, the bottom margin is set to 160px... setting that to 0 helps get you part of the way and doesn't affect FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, that worked to reduce the margin, though it still looks bigger on IE: http://www.carleighmac.org/.

Comment: The fact that reducing this margin from 160px to 0 changes IE but not FireFox or Chrome suggests you have some quirks in your design.  Typically I find that if I have this situation, I have made some part of the design too complex and it can be simplified to make it work more consistently.

Answer (score 1):

At your style.css ~line 1309

Try making the margin like this on the #navigation

margin: -55px auto auto auto;

Hope this helped.